# MagicalRecord crashes on importFromObject:

Tags: iphone, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm a little bit out if luck here. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction. I'm trying to make the MagicalRecord importFromObject method work. What I have is this:

- iOS SDK 5.1
- Basic XCode iPhone project setup (Empty application, no coredata, ARQ)
- CoreData framework added manually to the project
- Added coredata data model with one entity
- The entity has on attribute "title"

Prefix.pch contains this:

```
#define MR_SHORTHAND
#import "CoreData+MagicalRecord.h"
```

This code crashes:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStack]; 
    [Product importFromObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"test" forKey:@"title"]]; // Crashes here with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

    ....
}
```

It crashes in NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m in this method:

```
+ (NSArray *) MR_executeFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    __block NSArray *results = nil;
    [context performBlockAndWait:^{    

        NSError *error = nil;    

        results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; // Crashes here with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

        if (results == nil) 
        {
            [MagicalRecord handleErrors:error];
        }    

    }];
    return results; 
}
```

Comment: Whatis you **Product** representation in Core Data Model?

Comment: @Nikita: The whole setup is totally standard. Just the Product entity with an optional "title" attribute of type string. No relationships, no fetched properties.

Comment: @nhyolo Have you been able to fix this in the mean time?

Comment: @nhyolo Have you fixed this issue? I'm getting the same thing

Comment: I think it's still a bug: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/214

Answer (score 2):

You are likely to have these kind of crashes because you did not add the attribute "productID" (Entity Name + ID) (type String) to your model.

If you don't want to add a productID attribute, you can also refer it by adding the key relatedByAttribute (value : a primary attribute of your entity) to your entity User Info.